# using .der certificate in python/flask

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, flask, ssl-certificate

I have a python flask app  where  I  created a   cert   and  key file  using ssl and put that   in the  code  as follows

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    context=('cert.crt','keys.key')
    app.run('0.0.0.0',ssl_context=context,debug=True)
```

However they are  not valid. In the  server   I have  deployed the   code  there  are  2 files `'sslca-chain.der'` and `'SSLCA-Chain.pem'`. How  do I use  that  in the   code  instead   of the  above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two files you have mentioned are the same thing (chain certificates) just in different formats.

It is best to configure a reverse proxy (like nginx) to handle the SSL stuff rather than include it in your flask application.

Python only handles `PEM` format files natively.

However, if you must - you need two files - the certificate file, and the key file.

If you got your certificate from a third party CA, then they will provide you the certificate file.

The key file is always with you, and should be kept secret.

Since you have a certificate chain, you must provide a custom context to the application and include all the files in your chain, as the [`load_cert_chain` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) only takes one argument for the certificate file.

So, in short what you have to do is:

1. Make sure your PEM file contains your server certificate.
2. Create a custom context with the PEM file and your key file.
3. Pass this custom context to Flask

A PEM file is just a text file that contains all the certificates in a specific order; the order is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Primary SSL certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Intermediate certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Root certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

*The `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` lines are important and should be included*

Once you have verified that your PEM file contains your server certificate, here is how you would configure it for flask:

```
import ssl

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) # use TLS to avoid POODLE
ctx.load_cert_chain('/path/to/sslca-chain.pem', '/path/to/server.key')
app.run('0.0.0.0',ssl_context=ctx,debug=True)
```

Comment: strangely enough  I have the  pem file  where  I have 2 entries  under sperate ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----  and  ------END CERTIFICATE------. Not   sure where  the  key file  is. Is there  a way to find that  out. ?? Using Windows  server 2008  64-bit

Comment: You will have multiple `---BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and `----END CERTIFICATE---` line pairs; one for each of the intermediary certificates all the way up to the root certificate (the last pair). If you don't know where the key file is, ask the person who obtained the certificate for you; as it is generated at the time of the request.