# Is there a way to store the information from '.pem' certificates in a variable and use it with Flask's ssl_context?

Tags: python, flask, ssl

I want to know if there is a way to store in two strings my certificates for a Python Flask app.

Let's say I have these two strings:

```
cert_string = "AAAAAAAAAA"
key_string = "BBBBBB"
```

I want to know if I can do something like this that would give me the expected type and also store the correct value for my certificates.

```
appCert = someAPI/someCast(cert_string)
appKey= someAPI/someCast(key_string )
```

In the end I would like to call the Flask app like this:

```
app.run(port = 443, host = "0.0.0.0", ssl_context = (appCert, appKey))
```

I tried with StringIO but no success.

My main goal is to have the certificates inside my script and not in different files. I know I can pass the path to the certificates but I want to want to see if I can get rid of them and save them inside my file as text.

Thanks

Comment: "My main goal is to have the certificates inside my script and not in different files. " You are not explaining why you want to do that, but in general it is a bad idea because certificates change (they have an end of validity date) plus including the key is a secret and it is a bad idea to store a secret inside code, that could be pushed to public forges and so on. Keeping the secret outside of the code, with the relevant certificate allows to protect it better. It also allows far more easily to run your code on different situations aka with different certificates.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423326/6368697 for a beginning of an answer. Generate the "SSL" context yourself, and initialize it with your cert+key as strings(bytes more precisely), then pass it to Flask.